# Upload a pg database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, pgadmin

I am creating a mobile application and struggle with uploading my server (nodejs) and database (postgres using pgadmin).
I do not really understand how I can upload my database online (on an amazon server).

I tried to do researches but did not find what I was looking for (or most likely did not know where to look).

The only thing I found was a way to export the tables one by one in csv, but isn't there a way to export it so the files keep being updated once the database is updated?

I am sorry if some things aren't clear do not hesitate to ask more details.

Comment: I think you're asking how you can migrate an existing on-premise PostgreSQL database into AWS and then how you can maintain the two DBs in sync if updates are made to the on-premise DB. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.html.

Comment: Yes, or maybe would it be easier to directly create the database into AWS? Thanks anyway for the link I will carefully check this

Comment: Not sure what your question is, but it would certainly be simpler to maintain one DB than two and it would be simpler to create and manage a DB using RDS than doing it yourself (it would cost more but save time and effort, hopefully).

Answer (score 1):

You can use pg_dump and use the file to re-create the db.

```
pg_dump <database> > ~/<filename>.sql
```

Enter postgresql shell (psql).

Then create the database on Amazon server.

```
CREATE DATABASE <database>;
```

Then from the shell use psql to import the tables and data:

```
psql -d <database> -a -f <filename>.sql
```

You can transfer your file to Amazon EC2 via scp,

```
scp -i <ssh_key> ~/<filename>.sql <username>@<ip>:~/<filename>.sql
```

The username can be ubuntu or ec2-user or any other, depending upon the instance.

You can research `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` also. You can take data only backup also, if you already have tables.